# Cant send a cookie from Node app with proper config

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a controller made just to test cookies:

```
export const checkCookie = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Hello" });
};
```

and then router:

```
router.get("/login", checkCookie);
```

and in postman i get:

```
{
    "message": "Hello"
}
```

i have `app.ts` file:

```
import express, { Express } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
//
import userRouter from "./routes/userRoutes";
import cardsRouter from "./routes/cardsRoutes";
import contactsRouter from "./routes/contactsRoutes";
import transferRouter from "./routes/transferRoutes";
import authRouter from "./routes/authRoutes";
//
const app: Express = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//   console.log("hello from the middleware 2 ");
//   next();
// });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("name", "Test");
  res.cookie("cookieName", "1", {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000),
    httpOnly: true,
  });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.cookies);
});

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:4200",
  })
);

app.use("/api/v1", [
  userRouter,
  cardsRouter,
  contactsRouter,
  transferRouter,
  authRouter,
]);

export default app;
```

I want to set a cookie after a call from the client:

```
  url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login';
  token: string = '';

  async login(formObject: any) {
    console.log('logging');
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${this.url}`, { withCredentials: true });
      console.log(res.data);
      console.log('http cookie set!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

the console says:

```
logging
Object { message: "Hello" }
http cookie set!
```

But when i go to `dev tools -> storage -> cookies` theres no cookie.

Why i cant set a cookie with Node.js? I have cookie-parser, and i dont have any idea why i dont have this cookie.

edit:
i tried adding:

```
res.send(req.cookies);
```

but it didnt help.